# Who are the three messengers sent to the city in Surat Yasin?

Tags: quran, tafseer

In [Surat Yasin 36:13-14](https://quran.com/36/13-14/):

> وَاضْرِبْ لَهُم مَّثَلًا أَصْحَابَ الْقَرْيَةِ إِذْ جَاءَهَا الْمُرْسَلُونَ
>   إِذْ أَرْسَلْنَا إِلَيْهِمُ اثْنَيْنِ فَكَذَّبُوهُمَا فَعَزَّزْنَا بِثَالِثٍ فَقَالُوا إِنَّا إِلَيْكُم مُّرْسَلُونَ
>
> And present to them an example: the people of the city, when the messengers came to it when We sent to them two but they denied them, so We strengthened them with a third, and they said, "Indeed, we are messengers to you."
>
> *Wadrib lahum mathalan as-haba al-qaryati ith ja'aha al-mursaloon ith arsalna ilayhimu ithnaynifakaththaboohuma faAAazzazna bithalithinfaqaloo inna ilaykum mursaloon.*

Who are those three who were sent to the city to convince the people there?

Answer (score 3):

Had there been any value in specifying the name of the city and the names of the messengers, Allah would have revealed them in the verse, or through a hadith by the Prophet, or his companions would have asked about them. The verse warns the people of Mecca of what happens to those who do not follow the messengers: [It was not but one shout, and immediately they were extinguished](https://quran.com/36/29).

Having said that, there are several views. The most prevalent view is that the city was Antioch (in modern-day Turkey), which was ruled by a king called Antiochus. The three messengers were Sādiq, Sadūq, and Shalōm. This is what Ibn Kathir considered the most likely view based on narrations attributed to Ibn 'Abbas, Ka'b al-Ahbār, and Wahb ibn Munabbih.

Comment: Ibn Kathir actually refuted that view in his tafsir. History testifies that Antioch was not destroyed by a divine punishment

Answer (score 0):

There was a reference of 3 prophets in Gabriel Revelation found in 2007 which afterward was smuggled in a stone outside current Israel. The scripture was written in ink and the notion of representing the text is almost likely the Torah. This may be one of the miracles of the Quran and authenticity that it came from God(Allah). The scripture dated to the first century BC.

[image]
[image]

They are the latest archaeological invention and I did not find any article about the revelation from any Muslim scholar. I am not saying it is an absolute reference to that three prophets or it is an authentic source but the scholar should put a look at it and may publish articles to ensure the authenticity or eligibility of it.